# I can't get my ListFragment to Display data android

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-listfragment

I am working on a small project to help me learn about Android. I made a small ListFragment, but I cannot get it to display anything. I try checking the logs and I don't see any errors.

**ListFragment**

```
public class EspnFragment extends ListFragment {
    String URL = "url"
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    EspnAdapter adapter;
    EspnObject object = new EspnObject();
    private ArrayList<EspnObject> objects = new ArrayList<EspnObject>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new EspnAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_display);
        sendRequest();
        adapter.addAll(objects);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setListShown(true);
    }
    private void sendRequest() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                try {
                    Log.v("ESPN DATA:", "Getting Data");
                    httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(request);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                    String json = reader.readLine();
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("headlines");
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) items.get(i);
                        String title = jsonObj.getString("headline");
                        String date = jsonObj.getString("lastModified");
                        object.setDate(date);
                        object.setTitle(title);
                        objects.add(object);
                    }
                    Log.v("ESPN DATA:", "Done");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                    Log.v("ESPN DATA:", "Caught Error" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment you call `sendRequest` it would run on a separate thread. `addAll` & `notifyDataSetChanged` won't add anything cuz by the time you call them `objects` would still be empty

Move

```
    adapter.addAll(objects);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to your thread's run method